# Delphi - Iterating through an XML dataset with NativeXML

Tags: delphi, xml-parsing, delphi-2006, nativexml

I'm trying to migrate some xml code from the default delphi XML routines to NativeXML, hopefully to improve the speed (a lot).

The XML files are of the form:

```
<Datafile>
  <Header>
    <Name>'My Name'</Name>
    <Address>'My Address'</Address>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <ValuesSets>
      <ValuesSet>
        <v>1</v>
        <v>2</v>
        <v>3</v>
        <v>4</v>
      </ValuesSet>
      <ValuesSet>
        <v>5</v>
        <v>6</v>
        <v>7</v>
        <v>8</v>
      </ValuesSet>
    </ValuesSets>
  </Body>
</Datafile>
```

My problem is how to iterate through each of the sets of values.  A more or less direct translation of the old code didn't work:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
    AXMLDoc       : TNativeXML ;
    FileID        : TFilename ;
    I             : Integer ;
    J             : Integer ;
    HeaderNode    : TXMLNode ;
    BodyNode      : TXMLNode ;
    ValuesSetsNode : TXMLNode ;
    ValuesSetNode  : TXMLNode ;

    Values         : array of array of integer ;

begin
try
    Memo1.Lines.Clear ;
    FileID := 'Sample.XML' ;
    Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile (FileID) ;
    AXMLDoc := TNativeXml.Create (nil) ;
    AXMLDoc.LoadFromFile (FileID) ;

    if Assigned(AXMLDoc.Root) then
        begin
        HeaderNode := AXMLDoc.Root.NodeByName ('Header') ;
        if Assigned (HeaderNode) then
            begin
            //  < process header items >
            BodyNode := AXMLDoc .Root.NodeByName ('Body') ;
            if Assigned (BodyNode) then
                begin
                ValuesSetsNode := BodyNode.NodeByName ('ValuesSets') ;
                if Assigned (ValuesSetsNode) then
                    begin
                    SetLength (Values, ValuesSetsNode.NodeCount) ;
                    for i := 0 to ValuesSetsNode.NodeCount - 1 do
                        begin
                        ValuesSetNode := ValuesSetsNode [i] ;
                        if Assigned (ValuesSetNode) then
                            begin
                            SetLength (Values [i], ValuesSetNode.NodeCount) ;
                            for j := 0 to ValuesSetNode.NodeCount - 1 do
                                begin
                                Values [i, j] := StrToIntDef (ValuesSetNode [j].Value, 0) ;
                                end ;
                            end ;
                       end ;
                    end ;
                end ;
            end ;
        end ;

    for i := 0 to Length (Values) - 1 do
        begin
        for j := 0 to Length (Values [i]) - 1 do
            begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add (Format ('Values [%d, %d] = %d', [i, j, Values [i, j]])) ;
            end ;
       end ;

finally
    FreeAndNil (AXMLDoc) ;
    end ;
end ;
```

The output I get is:

```
Values [1, 0] = 0
Values [1, 1] = 1
Values [1, 2] = 0
Values [1, 3] = 2
Values [1, 4] = 0
Values [1, 5] = 3
Values [1, 6] = 0
Values [1, 7] = 4
Values [1, 8] = 0
Values [3, 0] = 0
Values [3, 1] = 5
Values [3, 2] = 0
Values [3, 3] = 6
Values [3, 4] = 0
Values [3, 5] = 7
Values [3, 6] = 0
Values [3, 7] = 8
Values [3, 8] = 0
```

and I was expecting:

```
Values [0, 0] = 1
Values [0, 1] = 2
Values [0, 2] = 3
Values [0, 3] = 4
Values [1, 0] = 5
Values [1, 1] = 6
Values [1, 2] = 7
Values [1, 3] = 8
```

so it seems as if the `Nodes` property of `TNativeXML` is not exactly the same as `IXMLNode`'s `ChildNodes` property.

How do I iterate all the child nodes within a parent node?  I don't want to give each one a unique name (`<v1001>1234</v1001>, <v1002>4321</v1002>...` etc), as I only ever need to access them sequentially, and don't want the speed penalty (or increased file size) of having to do a `NodeByName` for every value (there can be many of these values).

UPDATE **

NativeXML does have an equivalent to `ChildNodes` - it's called `Containers` (not `ChildContainers` as the online documentation would have you believe).  The following worked:

```
var
    AXMLDoc       : TNativeXML ;
    FileID        : TFilename ;
    I             : Integer ;
    J             : Integer ;
    HeaderNode    : TXMLNode ;
    BodyNode      : TXMLNode ;
    ValuesSetsNode : TXMLNode ;
    ValuesSetNode  : TXMLNode ;

    Values         : array of array of integer ;

begin
try
    Memo1.Lines.Clear ;
    FileID := 'Sample.XML' ;
    Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile (FileID) ;
    AXMLDoc := TNativeXml.Create (nil) ;
    AXMLDoc.LoadFromFile (FileID) ;

    if Assigned(AXMLDoc.Root) then
        begin
        HeaderNode := AXMLDoc.Root.NodeByName ('Header') ;
        if Assigned (HeaderNode) then
            begin
            //  < process header items >
            BodyNode := AXMLDoc .Root.NodeByName ('Body') ;
            if Assigned (BodyNode) then
                begin
                ValuesSetsNode := BodyNode.NodeByName ('ValuesSets') ;
                if Assigned (ValuesSetsNode) then
                    begin
                    SetLength (Values, ValuesSetsNode.ContainerCount) ;
                    for i := 0 to ValuesSetsNode.ContainerCount - 1 do
                        begin
                        ValuesSetNode := ValuesSetsNode.Containers [i] ;
                        if Assigned (ValuesSetNode) then
                            begin
                            SetLength (Values [i], ValuesSetNode.ContainerCount) ;
                            for j := 0 to ValuesSetNode.ContainerCount - 1 do
                                begin
                                Values [i, j] := StrToIntDef (ValuesSetNode.Containers [j].Value, 0) ;
                                end ;
                            end ;
                       end ;
                    end ;
                end ;
            end ;
        end ;

    for i := 0 to Length (Values) - 1 do
        begin
        for j := 0 to Length (Values [i]) - 1 do
            begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add (Format ('Values [%d, %d] = %d', [i, j, Values [i, j]])) ;
            end ;
       end ;

finally
    FreeAndNil (AXMLDoc) ;
    end ;
end ;
```

It's actually pretty slow - to read 32k float values takes many 10's of seconds.

Comment: +1 Well, with `containers` simple and clear. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

OP :

> so it seems as if the Nodes property of TNativeXML is not exactly the
>   same as IXMLNode's ChildNodes property.

You are right . There must be something more to be done to achieve this result.

[image]

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
[...]
    i , i2        : Integer ;
    j , j2        : Integer ;
[...]
begin
try
    Memo1.Lines.Clear ;
    [...]
            BodyNode := AXMLDoc .Root.NodeByName ('Body') ;
             if Assigned (BodyNode) then
             begin
                 ValuesSetsNode := BodyNode.NodeByName ('ValuesSets') ;
                 if Assigned (ValuesSetsNode) then
                 begin
                     SetLength (Values, ValuesSetsNode.NodeCount) ;
                     ValuesSetNode := ValuesSetsNode.NodeByName('ValuesSet') ;
                     if Assigned (ValuesSetNode) then
                     begin
                       i2:=0;
                        for i := 0 to ValuesSetSNode.NodeCount - 1 do begin
                         if i > 0 then ValuesSetNode := ValuesSetsNode.NextSibling(ValuesSetNode) ;
                         if ValuesSetNode=nil then break;
                         if ValuesSetNode.NodeCount > 0 then begin
                            SetLength(Values[i2], ValuesSetNode.NodeCount) ;
                            j2:=0;
                               for j := 0 to ValuesSetNode.NodeCount - 1 do begin
                                if pos(#13,ValuesSetNode[j].Value) > 0 then continue;
                                Values [i2, j2] := StrToIntDef (ValuesSetNode[j].Value, 0) ;
                                inc(j2);
                               end ; // for j
                           SetLength(Values[i2],j2);
                           inc(i2);
                         end;
                        end ; // for i
                     end;     // ValuesSetNode
                 end;         // ValuesSetsNode
             end;             // BodyNode
        end;                  // HeaderNode
    end;                      // AXMLDoc.Root

[...] 

finally
    FreeAndNil (AXMLDoc) ;
    end ;
end ;
```

Delphi 5 / Delphi XE2  NativeXml 4.07

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I figured it out - it's actually simpler than that (I've added the updated code as an addendum to the question)